# Cómo separar el DOM de la lógica en Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, lógica

respetada comunidad.

Actualmente me encuentro en la elaboración de un proyecto en Jvascript, pero uno de los requisitos es el siguiente:

**Keep the application logic separated from DOM manipulation tasks.**

Me gustaría saber que formas hay de hacer esto, creando algun archivo externo? o todo en un mismo archivo?

A decir verdad no sé como implementar esta tarea ya que en una misma funcíón puede haber tanto lógica como manipulación del DOM, entonces, como se pueden tener de manera independiente?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: La pregunta es basada en opiniones y eso generaría su cierre

Comment: No es tanto una opinión, consiste en saber si alguien ha implementado el DOM y la lógica de forma separada, de ser así que por favor comparta como implementó dicha tarea.

Comment: Pues precisamente eso son opìniones amigo, por que depende de la lógica de cada uno que lo haya hecho esa será la respuesta, considera leer [ask] y de paso hacer el [tour]

Comment: No entendiste mi pregunta pero bueno, ya alguien me ha ayudado, gracias

Comment: Soy nuevo en la comunidad, pienso que si algo estoy haciendo mal hay mejores maneras de apoyar y corregir, esta es una comunidad de apoyo y no de juicio

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a [es.so]. No te tomes de modo personal los comentarios de otro usuarios, es una recomendación para evitar disgustos o malos ratos. Por otro lado, lo que la comunidad intenta decirte es que tu pregunta es bastante amplia y habrá diferentes opiniones en cuanto a la misma. Puedes leer lo que dice el [help/dont-ask], sobre el tipo de preguntas que debemos evitar hacer en el sitio. Saludos

Comment: Hola Mauricio, gracias por la bienvenida, a decir verdad no lo tomo personal, uno de los comentarios fué eliminado por el usuario por eso quizá pareciera que lo tomo personal, además el modo en que tu me lo dices y expones es un poco más claro, entendiendo que soy nuevo en la comunidad. Mi pregunta no generaría malos entendidos, es un aspecto técnico que se debe tener en cuenta cuando se trabaja con Javascript y la , manipulación con el dom y solo estaba consultando al respecto, ya que no he podido encontrar información al respecto, pero bueno gracias de todos modos, buen dia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por favor ignora los comentarios.

En el código puse comentarios para orientarte mejor.
Por lo general, si quieres separar la lógica del DOM se utilizan diferentes scripts para no mezclar funciones, así obtienes un proyecto mejor organizado.

```js
//----------------Esta parte sería un script de lógica----------------
//Supongamos que los datos de la base de datos vienen de esta manera:

const dbData = [
{
  Nombre: "Luis Perez",
  Edad: 25
},
{
  Nombre: "Alejandra Scott",
  Edad: 27
}]

//Supongamos que debemos tener el apellido por separado, entonces creamos una función de lógica para formatear el objeto

function FormatearData(data){
  return data.map(row => ({
    Nombre   : row.Nombre.split(' ')[0],
    Apellido : row.Nombre.split(' ')[1],
    Edad     : row.Edad
  }))
}

//Ahora creamos una funcion para crear el html que necesitaremos:
function GetHtmlRows(data){
  return data.map(row => 
  `
   <tr>
    <td>${row.Nombre}</td>
    <td>${row.Apellido}</td>
    <td>${row.Edad}</td>
   </tr>
  `).join('')
}

//---------Esta parte sería OTRO script de manipulación del DOM-----------
//Ahora si, ya tenemos toda la lógica que necesitamos, ahora tenemos que crear una función para setear las rows, aquí si vamos a manipular el DOM.

function SetTableData(idTbody, data){
  const div = document.getElementById(idTbody)
  
  const dataFormateada = FormatearData(data) //Hacemos uso de la función
  const html = GetHtmlRows(dataFormateada)
  
  div.innerHTML = html
}

//Ahora simplemente llamamos a la función
SetTableData("rows", dbData)
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellido</th>
    <th>Edad</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
  <tbody id="rows">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu ejemplo está genial, lo estoy ejecutando y me da una buena idea para implementarlo en mi proyecto. Creo que en el caso de tu ejemplo, lo que haré será crear archivos separados y usar la exportación e importación de módulos, un módulo podría destinarse únicamente para el DOM y otro para la Lógica. Me gusta el manejo de filas que propones, estoy tratando de comprender este concepto a profundidad porque considero que es una buena práctica para tener un proyecto organizado tal como planteas, gracias por comentar el código y por tu ayuda, lo valoro mucho gracias!

Comment: Hola, de nada! me alegra que te haya servido!. Si necesitas más tips o ayuda puedes contactarme por twitter: @leoocast10.. Me ayudaría que pusieras la respuesta como aceptada y la votaras hacia arriba, jaja. Gracias.

Comment: jeje Listo ya lo he hecho, disculpa no haberlo hecho antes, recién me estoy familiarizando con la plataforma, gracias de nuevo :)